# How to get the media that owns a file?

Tags: 8, media, files

I have a file and I know there is a media that references it. How can I get this media?

In the opposite direction, knowing the media id, I can get the file:

```
$media = Media::load($mid);
$fid = $media->field_media_image->target_id;
$file = File::load($fid);
```

But now I know the file id and I want the media. How can I get it?

Comment: Use [loadByProperties()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21EntityStorageBase.php/function/EntityStorageBase%3A%3AloadByProperties/8.2.x)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `entityQuery`:

```php
$fid = 13141;
$usedIn = \Drupal::entityQuery('media')
  ->condition('field_media_image.target_id', $fid)
  ->execute();
```

Example response:

```
Array
(
    [15105] => 13109
)
```